# How to check if file was created by test in ctest

Tags: cmake, ctest

`ctest` framework is great framework for testing output and error code. E.g.:

```
add_test(NAME VersionTest COMMAND myapp.exe --help)
set_tests_properties(VersionTest PROPERTIES PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION "Version: 2.2.2")
```

In my case, an executable apart from output and error code creates also file (e.g. `res.json`)

I would like `ctest` also validate if file was created.
How I can do that?

I am expecting that if file was not created the test will fail (The `ctest --test-dir build` command run all tests and the one that check file existence will fail). I do NOT want to validate `res.json` file contents etc., only its existence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution I came up with. It requires 3.18 though since it uses the new `cat` functionality though.

```bash
set(json_file ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/res.json)

# Create the json file (In my example I use CMake to create the file)
add_test(NAME create_file COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${json_file})

# This test will be run after create_file since we defined the dependency.
# cmake -E cat <file> will fail if the file doesn't exist.
add_test(NAME check_file_exists COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E cat ${json_file})
set_tests_properties(check_file_exists PROPERTIES DEPENDS create_file)
```

NOTE: You can use [other CMake builtin command-line tools](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#run-a-command-line-tool) like `md5sum` instead of `cat` to verify the files existence. However, I'd argue it's a little non-intuitive.

It's common to `cat` a file to check it's contents.

Also using `cat` sets you up to use other test properties like `PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION` if you wanted to.